# Flutter modal bottom sheet full height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was trying things out with `ModalBottomSheet`. How can I achieve 90% height of device screen size for modal sheet. I did mediaquery but still it does not give me more than half of the screen size. How do I solve this?

Here is the code:

```
class _TestFileState extends State<TestFile> {
  modalSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0), topRight: Radius.circular(15.0)),
        ),
        builder: (context) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.email),
                title: Text('Send email'),
                onTap: () {
                  print('Send email');
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
                title: Text('Call phone'),
                onTap: () {
                  print('Call phone');
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text('Testing Modal Sheet')),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              modalSheet();
            },
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.indigo,
                height: 40,
                width: 100,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Click Me',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 23):

you have to pass isScrollControlled: true and use mediaquery as given below

```
showModalBottomSheet(
            isScrollControlled: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                color: Colors.red,
                //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              );
            });
```

Comment: Thankful for this. I was unaware about isScrollControlled.

Comment: @khadga I need it to be not dismissable, any ideas?

Comment: @AliBakhtiyari You might want to pass "isDismissible: false," to the showModalBottomSheet() function.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember that's a restriction about the native implementation of Flutter modal bottom sheet.

You can use the package [modal_bottom_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet) to achieve that.

Install:

```yaml
dependencies:
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^0.2.2
```

And minimal example:

```dart
showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  expand: true, //this param expands full screen
  builder: (context, scrollController) => Container(),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response :)